# MATlab GUI error: conversion to double from cell is not possible (string/array manipuilation problems)

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, user-interface, matrix

I am trying to create a user interface with a popup menu that will allow the user to select a channel of data to analyze. So I need to set the pop-up menu string to present only the number of channels available in a given data file.

The menu should look something like this when the arrow is clicked:

**Select Channel**

----------**1**-----------

----------**2**-----------

----------**3**-----------

My code for this section is as follows:

```
%%create a variable to list the number of channels in this data
string=(1:channels)


%%create variable for desired popup string
dropbox_string=('Select Channel", string)

%%set pop-up menu string
set(get(handles.popupmenu2, 'string'), dropbox_string)
```

The error is as follows: Conversion to double from cell is not possible.

I'm sure there's some manipulation that needs to take place with my 'string' and 'dropbox_string' variables I'm just not sure what.

Thanks

Comment: First of all, your code is not syntactically correct: 1) `'Select Channel"` starts with single quote and ends with double quote which has no meaning in MATLAB. 2) the round parentheses in the definition of `dropbox_string` don't really make sense. What was your intention?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look something like:

```
%create a variable to list the number of channels in this data
strings=arrayfun(               ...
        @num2str, 1:channels,   ...
        'UniformOutput', false  ...
)


%create variable for desired popup string
dropbox_string={'Select Channel", strings{:}}

%set pop-up menu string
set(handles.popupmenu2, 'string', dropbox_string)
```

To be really sure that everything is okay, make sure that `handles.popupmenu2` is a valid graphic handle, and is a true Pop-up menu.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Ive been stuck on this for way too long. Thanks!

Comment: Now, if you could chose it as answer, it would be great. :-)

Comment: Yes, just the check-mark. If there were multiple answers, it would mark the one that you considered the right answer to your question. If you already checked it before my previous comment, I apologize.

Comment: Now when I go to get the selection on from the popup menu its telling me the selection is a {5x1 cell}  how do I identify the specific selection so I can create if statements for each choice? should I create a new question so I can be more clear and get you more reputation if you know the answer?

Comment: Your GUI is made in GUIDE? Or you create it programatically?

Comment: using GUIDE. I figured it out using the hints given by the GUIDE prewritten code. contents=cellstr(get(popup, 'string'))
channel=contents{get(popup,'value')}  and that gives the selected channel. in case anybody else happens to come across this. Thanks for the help LINK!

Comment: You were a lot of help on this question, would you mind checking out my latest question about derivatives/integrals to see if you have any ideas that might make things a little clearer for me? If not, no worries! thanks. @CST-Link